# Download latest ADT and it is juno

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-juno

I download the latest ADT 64 bit - adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624
and when I open it it not the usual ADT but eclipse JUNO.

What should I do?

Link to screenshot:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=241sgvd&s=8#.U60gJvl_tZ9

Comment: Instead of releasing a stable, decent IDE, they keep broking everything, changing the typography and adding shadow effects. This reminds me my day to day in your average startup.

Comment: This version is broken. 

Here is a related post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466609/eclipse-adt-bundle-not-working-properly][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466609/eclipse-adt-bundle-not-working-properly

Answer (score 2):

This adt comprises of android sdk and eclipse

Comment: yes, but why the eclipse don't seem like the adt I used to see. Now it's just JUNO

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your eclipse

Comment: I'v added link in my post

Comment: eclipse is not open in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It is a custom eclipse distribution by google based on Juno.
The ADT package also includes android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation. My previous ADT is adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321 which is 510 MB zipped and the latest one is 359 MB. Maybe they have scroogled the package

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same situation. The previous version 20140321 works fine. This new version launches a standard Eclipse Juno version, and the Window > Manage SDK and Manage AVD options do not appear. I can create Android projects though.

[Eclipse ADT Bundle Not Working Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466609/eclipse-adt-bundle-not-working-properly) explains the current broken adt-sdk 20140624 version and recommends going back to the previous version. I also added a comment there with a link to d/l the older working version of the adt-bundle.

Comment: This post offers more details on the situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466609/eclipse-adt-bundle-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, so you should redownload the latest stable version from this link and you will get back the working ADT:

https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip