# Eclipse ADT Bundle Not Working Properly

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, java-8, eclipse-adt

I've just downloaded the Eclipse ADT Bundle from official site: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html (specifically adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624.zip). I'm on Win 7 64 bit, I've MD5 match for the zip file, but Juno fails to load correctly (I'm running eclipse.exe with admin rights): no ADT plugin, no application title (generic Resource -), no SDK manager link, ecc.ecc.
My workspace folder is totally clean under c:/dev/android, I've latest 64-bit JDK installed (version 8 update 5).
I've also tried another pc with windows 8, with no luck. What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you face this problem by updating the sdk?

Comment: Yeah I updated SDK, then went back to eclipse with an error requiring ADT version 23, so i ended wiping old bundle and reinstalling the new one.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the entire adt-bundle from:

http://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321.zip

I completely removed the 20140624 bundle. I also renamed ~/.android to ~/.android.bak. 
Then I unzipped this previous 22.6.2 version and it ran fine. When you run the SDK Manager, do not update the first two items to v23, keep everything at this version.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug, Android developers recommend to **use the latest stable 22.6.2 version** (20140321), which you can download from this link as [AndroidUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3786455/androiduser) said, but this is the Windows version for a 64-bit operating system:

https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip

If you delete all files of that bad new version and replace it with these, you will **get back** the friendly-looking Eclipse-based and **working** ADT.

Answer (score 1):

I have also troubles with installing the latest ADT bundle for Win7 64bit (the mentioned version by Jumpa). 
I've tried it several days to get it working but for me there's now fix for the bundle.

Also using a previous version of the ADT bundle was with-out success because it stops working very quickly. It requires to update to v23 and that update was not working.

I have the following "workaround" (`install everything maunally until google fixed the adt bundle`):

- Download the Android SDK and update everything (http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23-windows.exe)
- Download Eclipse Indigo (I've installed the Java EE IDE version) (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Indigo/SR2)
- Add the ADT Plugin to Eclipse and download it. (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Now it looks like everything is working.

I'm new to Android devel and I'm doing a "HelloWorld" app and creating a new activity with the wizard failed with the adt bundle. Nothing was created but now with the manual installation everything is created (created resource & added the activity to the manifest).

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are some changes with the android studio (SDK & ADT Bundle)

i have been looking for adb and did not find the adt bundle but figured how to get it from the following steps :)

Do the following:
1. if you want android studio download it 
 http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html 
2. To get the SDK bundle 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

The next Step is download the zip or rar file and extract it to your Local Drive 
then use the SDK Manager to install the files manually