# Where can I download Eclipse Android bundle?

Tags: android, eclipse, download, sdk, bundle

Where can I download Eclipse Android Bundle? Google now directed you to download Android Studio or to download Eclipse SDK integration but I want to find Eclipse Android bundle. I searched in Google and Eclipse web site but can't find any link.

Do you know any **site**, **ftp** etc. to download bundle?

Thanks.

Comment: As google has announced that `Android studio` is official IDE for developing Android APP.There is no documentation from where to download ADT bundle for eclipse.

Comment: @Dhaval Gondaliya; Iam working on a project and after installing some plugins, Eclipse crashed. I want to continue with Eclipse, at least for this project.

Comment: have a look at this link to download complete bundle http://stackoverflow.com/a/24601365/1925394

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers-includes-incubating-components/neon3

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The [Android Developer pages](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) still state how you can download and use the ADT plugin for Eclipse:

1. Start Eclipse, then select **Help** > **Install New Software**.
2. Click **Add**, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the *Name* and the following URL for the *Location*: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
4. Click **OK**.
5. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click **Next**.
6. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click **Next**.
7. Read and accept the license agreements, then click **Finish**.
   If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click **OK**
8. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

---

Links for the Eclipse ADT Bundle (found using Archive.org's [WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20141113024741/http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html))
I don't know how future-proof these links are. They all worked on February 27th, 2017.

- [Windows x86-64](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip)
- [Windows x86](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip)
- [Mac OS x86-64](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip)
- [Linux x86](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip)
- [Linux x86-64](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip)

---

**Update (2015-06-29)**: Google [will end development and official support for ADT in Eclipse at the end of this year](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) and recommends switching to Android Studio.

Comment: He doesn't want the ADT plugin, he wants the *bundle*. You say `plugin/bundle` but those are not the same thing

Comment: I know google site but I want to download bundle: one file/link and all program with Android plugins

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: It looks like working; I am starting to download :) Thx.

Comment: Removed the -1. Future readers be aware that this is for windows only

Comment: Added Mac OS and Linux links

Comment: they should not have removed this download from the official site. Some of us are still comfortable with eclipse and would like to continue to use that.

Comment: Please note this may give you the "plugin already exists" error. Check my answer below to go around that.

Comment: links still working on 05/1/2016..I needed them for NDK stuff

Comment: What about other resources to download it? Im from iran?

Comment: A simpler solution is: at Eclipse, open Help -> Eclipse Marketplace... and search for ADT; then click Install on the ADT entry. It still works despite Google's promise to end the support.

Answer (score 14):

Here you can download adt bundles 2014-07-02:

windows 32 bit: https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip

windows 64 bit: https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

MacOS 64 bit:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip

Linux 32 bit:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip

Linux 64 bit:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip

Comment: Mac 64: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip Linux 86: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip Linux 64: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip

Comment: How are these any different to the ones I posted?

Comment: my guess is he is just trying to artificially inflate his SO activity. maybe he is taking a class and is required to answer something on stackoverflow.

Comment: sorry pattafeufeu,i'm new to android development,spend whole day searching for adt bundle, because according to developers site"android studio is native platform for developing android apps" .i think it may b helpful for newbies like me and in hurry never read your answer carefully..

Comment: don't just copy other peoples' links. I would recommend removing your answer.

Answer (score 8):

You don't actually need the bundle as the ADT can be used with just any latest Eclipse IDE.

---

1. Make sure you have JDK installed.

2. Download latest eclipse.
3. Download latest ADT plugin `ADT-XX.X.X.zip`. As of this answer the current version is [ADT-23.0.7.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.7.zip) (More versions at http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)
4. Open Eclipse and follow the following steps:

   - Open `Help` > `Install New Software` > `Add` > `Archive`
   - Navigate to where you downloaded your ADT plugin and select it.
   - Check `Developer Tools`, click `Next`, accept any licenses and `Finish`
5. After restarting Eclipse, if you are not able to open a layout file go to **step 4** but instead of selecting archive add https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ in the `Location:` textbox. Press `Ok`, update the ADT and restart Eclipse. Close and reopen the layout files and you'll be good to go.
6. Run the Android SDK Manager to update its components.

---

**EDIT**: The ADT plugin has long since been deprecated. For more information visit this link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

Google has ended support for eclipse plugin. If you prefer to use eclipse still you can download Eclipse Android Development Tool from

[ADT for Eclipse](http://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android/ADT/ADT-23.0.6.zip)

Comment: Thank You so much I had an e-book for android 4 development and I was really searching for it. Eclipse is fast and easy to use compared to IntelliJ products.

Answer (score -2):

Try www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers-includes-incubating-components/neonrc3