# What is the final version of the ADT Bundle?

Tags: adt, eclipse-adt

What is the final version of the ADT Bundle that was released by Google?

Since "*Android Studio*" was announced as official IDE for the development of Android apps, the *ADT Bundle* (Eclipse with ADT Plugin & Android SDK) cannot be downloaded from *developer.android.com* any longer. I also could not find a version history for the *ADT Bundle*.

I need the final version number in the form "*YYYYMMDD*", so I can determine the URL for downloading according to the following pattern (see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23457154/1364368)):

```
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-<YYYYMMDD>.zip
```

For example, the following download URL for version *20140702* (2nd July 2014) is still working:
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can i download Eclipse Android bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418096/where-can-i-download-eclipse-android-bundle)

Comment: I think you cannot find it now. you have to update it from SDK Manager

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For historic reasons, I leave you the links to the last versions of ADT:

- `linux 64 bit:` http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
- `linux 32 bit:` http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
- `MacOS X:` http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
- `Win32:` http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
- `Win64:` http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

After that, you can update ADT plugin after 20140702 version. This answer was intended for the ones starting from zero.

Comment: It really sucks that they pulled the download from the android dev download website. Android studio doesn't work very well with libgdx (i can't get to run desktop version of a game in AS), and is therefore useless to me. Shame on you, google :/

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the version *"20140702"* of the example link in the question was the final version, because I downloaded this file on the 12th November 2014, i.e. the version from the 2nd of July 2014 was still the latest version on 12th of November. When I try manually all the possible versions/dates between today in this date, then I always get a page with error code "404" (file not found), which indicates that no new version was released since the 12th of November.

Comment: no need to work hard: the Internet Time machine (a.k.a. archive.org) shows same result.

Comment: At [_this URL at archive.org_](http://web.archive.org/web/20141202044627/http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) you'll see the last version of the download page with the "ADT-Bundle" (captured at 2nd December 2014); click on _"VIEW ALL DOWNLOADS AND SIZES"_ to get the links for the download files.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get an updated version of the Eclipse's ADT plugin (based on an unreleased 24.2.0 version) that I managed to patch and compile at https://github.com/khaledev/ADT.

Comment: Hi Khaled, how to "tell" Eclipse to use yours ADT?

Comment: Hi VitalyD, first you need to install Eclipse from scratch (you can use the latest "Mars" version) and then install the plugin by going to Help -> Install New Software... Then choose the "Add..." button to add the plugin, name it "ADT" for instance and specify the location of the downloaded archive .zip file.

Comment: Hi Khaled, thanks for the answer, but where I can download ADT that includes your patch?

Comment: Ah of course you can get it on the main GitHub page from the changelog or directly from this link: [ADT-24.2.0-20160319](http://khaled-lakehal.com/ADT/ADT-24.2.0-20160319.zip)

Comment: @Khaled Lakehal thank you for maintaining this ADT. I would like to inquire from you whether it works with Android SDK 26.0.0 released in March 2017?  Good job you are doing. The other thing is, when will you be releasing the next ADT plugin for Eclipse?