# android emulator shows windows error while starting

Tags: android, eclipse

I Have installed eclipse kepler in my new Windows XP with 4gb ram.
Also installed sdk 20.0.2
when i created new emulator in avd it shows windows error.

"emulator-arm.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience"

I tried by reinstalling adt as well as sdk but no effect.
kindly tell me needful solution.

Thanx in advance

Specification of avd

Name: vijay

CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi-v7a)

Path: C:\Documents and Settings\ADMIN.android\avd\vijay.avd

Target: Android 5.0.1 (API level 21)

Skin: 720x1280

SD Card: 100M

Snapshot: no

hw.lcd.density: 320

hw.dPad: no

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.camera.back: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 200M

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

runtime.network.latency: none

skin.dynamic: no

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.cpu.model: cortex-a8

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.device.hash2: MD5:e6de262aae26d1ce2c8a8b656265afbc

hw.ramSize: 512

tag.id: default

tag.display: Default

hw.sdCard: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Generic

hw.mainKeys: yes

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.device.name: 4.7in WXGA

hw.battery: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

AvdId: vijay

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

hw.camera.front: none

hw.gps: yes

avd.ini.displayname: vijay

snapshot.present: no

vm.heapSize: 64

runtime.scalefactor: auto

Comment: Try installing the adt bundle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449206/what-is-the-final-version-of-the-adt-bundle

Comment: @Der Golem :ok i will download new adt bundle and check it.

Comment: Now i installed android studio but here also same problem is arriving. Is there any issue with my pc.

Comment: I refuse with all my strength to have anything to do with Android Studio. So, I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try Minimum API level=8 (that would be Android 2.2.) . Ensure that your JVM version is compatible.

Comment: Can you tell me which jvm version i have to use.I am using jdk1.7.0_76

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change configuration of AVDs and keep trying with different config like device,cpu,check GPU host and use less RAM size like 256 MB while creating AVDs.

i hope it will work.