# Where is the Eclipse ADT bundle link?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adt

On the official site for Android development I can no longer see the link for the Eclipse ADT bundle.

I cannot switch to Android Studio as my framework is Ant based currently and not [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) based.

Do I need to download Eclipse and ADT plugins separately, or is there an Eclipse ADT bundle link (if it still exists)?

Comment: with the release of android studio Eclipse is no longer supported and you will need to download everything separately. Eclipse will no longer get updated (for android support I mean) so I suggest you move to android studio as soon as possible

Comment: While that might be duplicate from latest version point of view but this post allow people to provide with the link for other ADT bundles too which many developers might require for some purpose!

Answer (score 78):

Here you can download adt bundles 2014-07-02:

windows 32:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip

windows 64:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Mac 64:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip

Linux 86:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip

Linux 64:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip

Comment: Mac 64:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip


Linux 86:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip

Linux 64:
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip

Comment: +1 for answer. 
Users must know that , this links are not longer available on google / android documentation. However they still support the plugin which can be installed on the eclipse. Download eclipse separately and install the adt plugin

Comment: This may be the last build of adt-bundle.  =(

Comment: For those who are still using Eclipse ADT bundle, check PattaFeuFeu's answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418096/where-can-i-download-eclipse-android-bundle#answer-27418547 

PS. please move on with adt and use AS.

Comment: @ralphspoon Please understand that Android Studio sucks ass at this moment. I'm not the only person having problems with AS. Just google and you'll find lots of people reporting problems.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they have some instructions for that here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Bit more complicated then before...

Comment: yeah you're correct, this is what I said that we need to download both of them separately. I don't know why old Android development links are removed as soon as newer version is released. They should take care of developers working on framework based on previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the Android Studio is the official editor, I believe android removed that option. But you can download adt as zip file here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: Yes, but thats not the complete bundle which I wanted.

Comment: Then, you should just search google. I saw there are other sites that has this bundle, if you trust.

Comment: The final version of the _ADT Bundle_ can still be downloaded if you know the URL, see _[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27583241/1364368)_.